# geom_text at certain position in a pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to create a pie chart with some labels displayed at certain location signifying whether a proportion test is significant or not. I have managed to create a basic pie chart and I have pasted the code below. I have also posted the desired result (created using MS Paint software) and would love any help I can get any creating this plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# defining the dataframe
df <-
  data.frame(
    condition = c('x', 'y', 'z'),
    cat = rep(c('a', 'b'), 3),
    freq = c(60, 34, 44, 40, 66, 56)
  )

# computing percentages
df <-
  df %>% group_by(condition) %>% mutate(label = freq / sum(freq) * 100)

# creating a pie chart
ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes('', freq, fill = cat)) +
  facet_grid(". ~ condition") +
  geom_col(position = 'fill') +
  geom_label(aes(label = label), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)  +
  ggplot2::theme_grey() +
  ggplot2::theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    legend.title.align = 0.5,
    legend.text.align = 0.5,
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.key = element_rect(size = 5),
    legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "lines"),
    legend.margin = margin(5, 5, 5, 5),
    legend.box.margin = margin(5, 5, 5, 5),
    panel.border = element_rect(
      colour = "black",
      fill = NA,
      size = 1
    ),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(
      color = "black",
      size = 14,
      hjust = 0.5
    ),
    plot.title = element_text(
      color = "black",
      size = 16,
      face = "bold",
      hjust = 0.5
    )
  ) +
  ggplot2::guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = base::list(colour = NA)))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Here is what the desired result looks like (notice that the text is always at the top and aligned to the center of the pie chart)-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? I used geom_text and specified `x = 1.6` to get labels outside the radius of the pie chart. Also, just a style tip, but you have a lot of unnecessary arguments in theme(), and you don't need to put `ggplot2::` before ggplot functions after loading the tidyverse. Also, if you'd like the pie chart to not have a small empty dot in the center of it, you can put `width = 1` in your call to `geom_col`.

```
    library(tidyverse)

    df <-
      data.frame(
        condition = c('x', 'y', 'z'),
        cat = rep(c('a', 'b'), 3),
        freq = c(60, 34, 44, 40, 66, 56), 
        sig =c("***", NA, "ns", NA, "**", NA)
      ) %>% 
      group_by(condition) %>% 
      mutate(label = freq / sum(freq) * 100)

    ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes('', freq, fill = cat)) +
      facet_wrap(~ condition, nrow = 1) +
      geom_col(position = 'fill', width = 1) +
      geom_label(aes(label = label), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
      geom_text(aes(label = sig, x = 1.6), position = position_fill(vjust = 1)) +
      coord_polar(theta = 'y') +
      theme_grey() +
      theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks = element_blank(),
            axis.text = element_blank(),
            axis.title = element_blank(),
            strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
            strip.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1),
            legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
            legend.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
            legend.position = "bottom",
            legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "lines"),
            panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1)) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NA)))
```

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzoxT.png)